# Conditional formatting of variable size table, based on values in array

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a table B2:H9 and I'm trying to highlight the cells that match the values in column K2:K9
[see sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRL62.png)

I can do conditional formatting in B2:H9 cells by using the EQUAL TO option - I select one cell in the column K2:K9 at a time, so I have to repeat the process 8 times.[see sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhuBK.png)

The problem I am running into is that both the table B2:H9 and the reference column K2:K9 will change size (sometimes will be 1000 rows or more) and it's impossible to repeat this task so many times.

Is there a faster way to do this? I tried the option "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" but had no luck - it seems to only work for individual cells but not for the full column K2:K9

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following:

1. select B2
2. set conditional formatting as `=B2=$K2`, press OK
3. in the `Applies to` section extend the range from B2 to B2:H9

as for B2 there is no $ it should change dynamically for both rows and columns, and for $K2 only row should change

Comment: Great - this works perfect. I kept trying and was able to make it work using MATCH but the process is a bit more convoluted. Your approach is more straightforward

Comment: good to hear, can you then accept the answer as the solution?